# confused about the table highlighting

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE friends
(
    id INTEGER
    name TEXT
    birthday Date
);
```

This is all in SQL.

I keep trying to create this table and `Date` keeps getting highlighted blue. I was watching the tutorial on it, and the instructor's `Date` was not getting highlighted blue. Trying to figure out if it is in issue on my end or a glitch with the software?

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to missing commas between columns

```
CREATE TABLE friends( id INTEGER, name TEXT ,birthday Date );
```

Comment: @Alexbbb you are welcome , please set the answer. thanks